# docker java compile and run with mysql driver not working

Tags: java, docker, classpath, javac

could someone help fix the dockerfile issue?
docker java compile and run with mysql driver not working. something wrong with cp command?
**Error: Could not find or load main class com.smartworks.client.RDSConnectionTest**

added ENV still no help
ENV CLASSPATH .;./target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar

**#linux image**

```
FROM alpine

COPY src /build/

COPY target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar /libs/

WORKDIR /build/


**#jdk image**

RUN apk add openjdk8

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk

ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin


**#compile and run app**

RUN javac -cp /libs/*.jar com/smartworks/client/RDSConnectionTest.java

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","/libs/*.jar","com.smartworks.client.RDSConnectionTest"]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Do you get an error message? If yes, then what is the exact error message? Error messages give you important clues about what's wrong. Don't just think "there's an error" and ignore what it tells you.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class com.smartworks.client.RDSConnectionTest